# Pagination links not working

Tags: php, pagination

I've searched through the web and can't really find what's the problem with my code. The next and prev links are not working. it only gets the first entry.

Hope you guys can help with this! Thanks.

```
<?php 
// ROWS DISPLAYED PER PAGE
$rows_per_page = 1;

// GET PAGE NUMBER
$page = $_GET['page'];
$offset = (!empty($page)) ? $page : $page = 1;

// URL CLEAN UP
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$self = str_replace("page={$offset}", "", $self); 

// GET LIST OF STATES
$offset = ($page) ? ($page - 1) * $rows_per_page : 0; 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE update_categoryID = '$id' ORDER BY update_date          DESC LIMIT {$offset},{$rows_per_page}";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die('Error, query failed');

// GET NUMBER OF PAGES
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE update_categoryID = '$id'"; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query1)or die('Error, query failed');
$total = mysql_num_rows($result1);
$NumPgs = ceil($total/$rows_per_page);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
?>
<h2><?php echo $row['update_title']; ?></h2>
 <p class="datetime"><?php echo $row['update_date'];?></p>
 <br>
 <p class="post"><?php echo $row['update_content'];?></p> 
 <a href="blogcomment.php?id=<?php echo $row['update_id'];?>">Post a Comment</a>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
<span style="float:right">
<? if ($NumPgs > 0 && $page!=1) {
echo "<a href=\"{$self}page=".($page- 1)."\">&lt;&lt;Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;"; } ?>
[Page <?php echo $page; ?>]
<? if ($page < $NumPgs) {
echo "<a href=\"{$self}page=".($page+1)."\">&nbsp;&nbsp;Next&gt;&gt;</a>"; } ?>
<b><? echo $offset+1;?> to <? echo $offset+$rows_per_page;?>, of <? echo $total; ?>  Entries</b>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm maybe your page param is appended to the query string, try this :

```
 $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".
         preg_replace( $_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ], 'page=[0-9]+', '');
```

instead of :

```
 // URL CLEAN UP
 $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 $self = str_replace("page={$offset}", "", $self);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short open tags are not working in your case.

https://www.php.net/echo

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Try the following code.

```
<?php 
    // ROWS DISPLAYED PER PAGE
    $rows_per_page = 1;

    // GET PAGE NUMBER
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $offset = (!empty($page)) ? $page : $page = 1;

    // URL CLEAN UP
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $self = str_replace("page={$offset}", "", $self); 

    // GET LIST OF STATES
    $offset = ($page) ? ($page - 1) * $rows_per_page : 0; 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE update_categoryID = '$id' ORDER BY update_date          DESC LIMIT {$offset},{$rows_per_page}";
    $result = mysql_query($sql)or die('Error, query failed');

    // GET NUMBER OF PAGES
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE update_categoryID = '$id'"; 
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1)or die('Error, query failed');
    $total = mysql_num_rows($result1);
    $NumPgs = ceil($total/$rows_per_page);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $row['update_title']; ?></h2>
     <p class="datetime"><?php echo $row['update_date'];?></p>
     <br>
     <p class="post"><?php echo $row['update_content'];?></p> 
     <a href="blogcomment.php?id=<?php echo $row['update_id'];?>">Post a Comment</a>
 <?php
}
?>
    <span style="float:right">
   <? echo ($prev = ($NumPgs > 0 && $page!=1) ? "<a href=\"{$self}&page=".($page- 1)."\">Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;": 
   "Prev&nbsp;&nbsp;"); ?>
    [Page <?php echo $page; ?>]
   <? echo ($next = ($page < $NumPgs) ? "<a href=\"{$self}&page=".     ($page+1)."\">Next</a>": 
    "Next");?>&nbsp;
    <b>&nbsp;<? echo $offset+1?> to <?=$offset+$rows_per_page?>, of <? echo $total?> Entries</b>
    </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: the problem is with <?= you have to replace them with <? echo

Comment: Hi, thanks! I've tried your code and modify it a little, yet it still can't work. Whenever i click on the "next" link, it still only show the first entry.

Comment: <span style="float:right"> 
      [Page 1]
   <a href="/guides.php?id=1page=2page=2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Next&gt;&gt;</a>    <b>1 to 1, of 2 Entries</b> 
    </span> 
this is the output i have now.